# How to enable "Extract String Resource" popup in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

In Android Studio while adding TextView to the layout xml file, it is very convenient to use "Extract String Resource" to add string name to strings.xml. But somehow its not appearing in the popup whether I click or press Alt + Enter (Windows 8 OS).

Is there anything I need to get that popup back?
Here is the screenshot of what the popup looks like now.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preform the action when the attribute is the value you want the string to be, or a string reference that doesn't exist, for example:

```
android:text="oh hi!"
```

or

```
android:text="@string/this_doesnt_exist_yet"
```

Comment: Thank you :). The first option in you answer working for me. As I type the actual string, "Extract String Resource" pops up and can add the resource name in strings.xml. Its very convenient as mismatch can be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

If that option doesn't appear when you press alt-enter on a string literal, you likely have it disabled. In Android Studio 3.1.4, it can be enabled by selecting `Help/Find Action...` (Ctrl-Shift-A) and searching for "Extract string resource". The actual path to the setting is `File/Settings/Editor/Intentions/Android/Extract string resource`. Either way, you'll want to enable it.